# cheeriojs has error: exports.load.initialize

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm using cheeriojs to do web scraping. I'm having problem after load the body into cheerio. I can see the body is well formatted html code. I'm getting some error like `exports.load.initialize`. I couldn't using the css selector any elements.

```
parseWebsite = function () {
    request.post(url, {
            followAllRedirects: true, headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
            }, form: formval
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            $ = cheerio.load(body);
            console.log('test');
            var table = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgCRF');//table: exports.load.initialize
            })
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out. I'm using webstorm and I think that "error" is part of webstorm thing. This actually wasn't an error at all.